# Photoshop a 3D STL file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, import

I have a 3d `STL` file that i would like to open and edit in `Photoshop`.
Is that possible ?

I can see that he won't let me open it.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can open that file type. Did you try 3D -> New 3D Layer from File...?

Comment: Tried that, he wouldn't let me. i get this "Could not complete the New Layer from 3D File command because the selected file is not a recognized 3D format."

Comment: What Photoshop version are you using?

Comment: Version 12 cs5 that what i use on a mac.\

Answer (score 1):

If you have a older Photoshop and/or problems with source files (it happens many CAD and other stl tools tend to break stl files). Then just convert it to **obj**:

- Here is a [Online 3D Mesh Converter](http://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/)
- or use something like [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) on a local computer.

The formats *OBJ*, *STL*  and *PLY*  are the *CSV*  files of the 3d world really easy to swap out to other formats. And easy to parse in nearly any app, or even in new code.

Comment: Thanks tried that, with object, it opened but its a very bad quality of image and you cant even rotate it (or you cant anyway rotate a 3d model in Photoshop ? )

Comment: @Curnelious it will be until you turn the preview mode off to render. Many stl files are in fact exported at bad quality if the author didn't know what they were doing (yes even pro CAD users do it all the time used to fix these things for years). Theres no way you will lose anything in a  stl to obj conversion. Note: Normals may have been wrong way around in solid works export and the resolution is by default very low.